# How can i set the polymer(wc) component's version in the api/doc page?

Tags: polymer, web-component, jsdoc

I'm making a custom web component using polymer and now i'm trying to write some documentation but i can't find a way to change/set the components version. I'm using the yeoman polymer seed element, and the "core-component-page" core component for the documentation creation. I have tryed:

```
@version 0.0.1
```

But with no success. Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## use bower

**and you can still use js doc if you like:**

```
/**
 * My web component does things i desc here
 * @version 1.2.3
 */
```

**on using bower:**
https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/distributing-components-with-bower.html

**in bower.json**

```
{
  name: 'polymer-demo',
  version: '0.0.1',
  description: 'An awesome Polymer element.',
  keywords: [
    'Polymer',
    'web-components'
  ],
  license: 'MIT',
  homepage: 'https://github.com/johnsmith/polymer-demo',
  ignore: [
    '**/.*',
    'node_modules',
    'bower_components',
    'test',
    'tests'
  ]
}
```